# How can a process in a container started as a Docker Compose service find out both its IPv4 and its IPv6 address?

Tags: docker, shell, docker-compose, network-programming

Within a service "foo" started as part of a Docker Compose stack of services I would like to be able to find out/know both the IPv4 and IPv6 address of the container the service is running in.

One way to find out is via the shell command `hostname -i`, but this only gives the IPv4 address. I'd also prefer one way to get both, if possible. Is there a way that Compose can pass the service its IPv4/6 addresses during startup? If not, can the service determine these from the Docker runtime after startup?

Irrelevant to the question, but I'll describe what I'm doing so people can understand the sense.

I've got Nginx also running in the stack. It has a rule like the following:

```
location ~ "^/foo/bar.*" {
    if ($http_x_hsn = "") {
        return 401 '{"error":"Invalid hsn"}';
    }
 
    # The resolver DNS name is resolvable by Docker.

    # Any instance of "foo" has a trivial DNS server built in
    # and can be used to resolve the IP address of a particular
    # "foo" instance which is associated with a particular value
    # of "hsn" passed in a the header "x-hsn" by looking up that
    # association which will have been centrally registered prior 
    # to the handling of this type of request. Of course, if
    # no association between foo instance IP and hsn is found the
    # DNS query will return no record and this request should
    # then fail.

    # Note that a particular foo instance is 1-to-1 with a 
    # particular value of hsn.

    resolver <DNS name resolving to any service foo instance>;

    # Given an "hsn" with value "bar", service foo
    # will be asked to resolve "foo-service.bar".
    # The IP address returned should be one visible to Nginx

    set $upstream_service foo-service.$http_x_hsn;

    # Now, proxy to the correct instance of foo, based on 
    # the value of "hsn"

    proxy_pass http://$upstream_service;
}
```

I've got this working using `os.networkInterfaces()` in foo (this is a Nodejs service), but the structure that returns can list multiple interfaces and I'm not sure that the one being used for the service would be always `eth0` so I thought I'd ask here if there's a better way.

I should also mention that the associations between hsn values and service instances will have been created by Nginx routing to an instance (via another location rule) in a round robin way, with that instance centrally registering its IP address with that particular hsn value.

Comment: As a user, normal commands like `ifconfig` should tell you...but you shouldn't usually need these addresses at all.  How will your application use them?

Comment: There's a bit of an elaborate setup I'm doing, but I didn't really want to get into that. I guess I can describe it so that people can understand the motivation behind the question.

Comment: In slightly more detail, a container runs in its own network namespace and has its own virtual network interface.  So if the container process calls, say, [getifaddrs(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getifaddrs.3.html) it can retrieve the container-private IP addresses.  But, the container-private addresses aren't really useful; you can only call them from the same Docker network, or from a native-Linux host.  You could also bind(2) to those addresses, in the same way you could a non-container host process.

Comment: Hopefully you can understand from my further elaboration why a container-private address _would_ be useful for my case, but I want to stick to methods of obtaining this info that I can call from Nodejs.